# Never or almost never changing Static IP to expose as a TCP traffic listener

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

Like the title says, I have a legacy application that requires manual whitelisting of ip:port to which it will send some data to the application I'm developing that consumes it.

I am looking for some advice on this, temporarily I have whitelisted the pod ip:port to keep the integration working.

It is not possible to automate dynamic whitelisting. It is not possible to use the hostname for ip resolution, the ports are not a problem here.

The legacy app is hosted on the same network outside of k8s cluster, and it is not possible to change anything related to connectivity apart from adding a single ip:port whitelist due to it being developed about 30 years ago.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but networking, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Since you're using EKS, surfacing your application behind a NLB would give you a stable IP address to point to. I would do it with an service+ingress and the NLB annotations as noted here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html